# Регулярное выражение для ссылок на YouTube

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. 
Необходимо проверять ссылку, что эта ссылка на YouTube видео.
Сделать можно с помощью функции `preg_match()`. А вот нужно регулярные выражения сделать. =)

Пример ссылки: `http://youtube.com/любое видео`
А вот как же сделать чтобы валидировал с `http://` и без него? =)
Кто знаешь как решить такую задачу? =) Заранее спасибо. =)

Comment: Звучит как заявка на проект на фрилансере :)

Что сделано ? что не получается ? Конкретнее плиз :)

Comment: Простите, да. Переборщил. =) Вообщем в регулярных выражениях не разбираюсь. =) Просто хотелось бы увидеть наброски выражений для preg_match. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За пример берем ссылку: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jPBqNw1uJA

```
<?
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jPBqNw1uJA¶m1=asd';
if (stripos($url, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
    preg_match('#v=([^\&]+)#is', $url, $videoId);
    if (count ($videoId) > 0) {
        //у нас есть id video, ссылка правильная
        // $videoId[1] - ID видео
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: а <pre lang="php">$videoData = parse_url($url); </pre> зачем ? :)

Comment: shurik, да, Вы правы, убрал :)